# Empty results in iTunes Store Search API

Tags: ios, api, app-store, itunes, itunes-store

I am using [iTunes Store Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) and I want to retrieve the app info by app id. The problem is that for some apps and some country codes API returns empty results.

For example:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=591764200&country=de - returns full info
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=591764200&country=us - does not return info

Can it be somehow connected to sale territories limitations?

Comment: If the app is restricted , api returns a empty . So you need to specify the country parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, if the app is not available or not for sale in that country, it won't be in the result list.

**UPDATE 1:**
i took another look at it: the app is actually a [bundle](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app-bundle/elektronika-super-bundle/id921989254) that contains 4 apps, from which only 2 are available in the US (Merry Cook HD and Space Bridge HD) and two are not available (Mysteries of the Ocean HD and Where Are My Eggs? HD)

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that either the app has territory restrictions and cannot be sold in the US, or the developer removed it from sale in the US. Try looking up the app in the actual app store and see if it is available. I suspect that it is not.